# show javascript array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm new in JavaScript.

I have an array with some values and I'd like to show each array values within a list.

#### This is my script

```
<script>
var fruits = "apple,banana,watermelon,coconut";
var plits = fruits.split(',');
function a(){
  for(i=0; i<plits.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>";
    //document.write("<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>");
  }
}
</script>

<button onclick="a()">show fruits</button>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Whenever i run the code, it only shows the latest value of the array.

Likewise when i use the commented script above, the page changed and it turns infinity loading.

How can i show the array values within the #output?

Comment: UL should be the parent of li elements. Also you have to concatenate the innerHTML like `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "<div>" + plits[i] + " fruit</div>";`

Comment: That is because you write all the values to the same spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) for it.

```js
function a() {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul'),
        li, i;

    for (i = 0; i < plits.length; i++) {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = plits[i];
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(ul);
    a = function () {};
}

var fruits = "apple,banana,watermelon,coconut",
    plits = fruits.split(',');
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">show fruits</button>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps !

Comment: #Impressed with your otherwise thinking ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre, what do you mean?

Comment: I have been reading your answers every now and then and I always find it different from others :)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>";
```

with

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>";
```

Complete function

```
function a(){
  var html = "<ul>";
  for(i=0; i<plits.length; i++)
  {
    html += "<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>";
  }
  html += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
}
```

For ensuring that `a()` is not invokable again, set it to null

```
function a(){
  var html = "<ul>";
  for(i=0; i<plits.length; i++)
  {
    html += "<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>";
  }
  html += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
  a = null;// or a = function(){}
}
```

Comment: @Rayon Also `li` cannot be a child of `div`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy fixed it

Comment: @RayonDabre true, took me more time than I thought ;)

Comment: thanks, it works! But, can you tell me how to make the function only works for 1 time?

Comment: @ArifZoel IIFE is the thing that you must be looking for.

Comment: @ArifZoel, You should not use `inline` event binding as you need to keep functions global..Use `JavaScript` event binding..`addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` will help!

Comment: @ArifZoel for making sure that this method is not invokable again, you can `a=null;` inside `a()` method definition.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Rayon Dabre, gurvinder372, thanks for your help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is replacing the innerHTML of the div in for loop.. But what you really needs to do is to append string in every itteration.

```
<script>
var fruits = "apple,banana,watermelon,coconut";
var plits = fruits.split(',');
function a(){
  var message = "<ul>";
  for(i=0; i<plits.length; i++){
     message += '<li>'+plits[i] + " fruit</li>";
  }
  message += '</ul>'
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = message;
}
</script>

<button onclick="a()">show fruits</button>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>
            var fruits = "apple,banana,watermelon,coconut";
            var plits = fruits.split(',');
            var content = '';
            function a(){
              for(i=0; i<plits.length; i++){
                content = content.concat("<li>" + plits[i] + " fruit</li>");  
              }
              document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content;
            }
            </script>

            <button onclick="a()">show fruits</button>
            <div id='output'></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0my1xx7c/

```
<button id='button'>show fruits</button>
<ul id='output'></ul>


<script>
var fruits = "apple,banana,watermelon,coconut";
var plits = fruits.split(',');
function a(){
  for(i=0; i<plits.length; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = plits[i] + ' ' + 'fruit';
    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(li);
  }
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', a, false);
</script>
```

Remarks:

- Don't append li items to a div, but a ul or ol element
- Instead of writing , add an id to the element and attach an event listener to it that executes the function after the button has been clicked
- Create and append elements instead of using innerHTML